# How to call notifyDataSetChanged() from a generic Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listadapter

An `OnItemClickListener` for a `ListView` has the following method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

I'd like to have the adapter behind the `ListView` refresh, and I believe this is done through the use of:

```
BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

How do I use the `parent` parameter in the `onItemClick` method to do this? So far I've tried:

```
parent.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This throws an error because the object returned is of class `HeaderViewListAdapter`, which for reasons unknown isn't a subclass of `BaseAdapter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't any method in HeaderListView for data refresh/reload. The only way I can think of doing this is to reassign the adapter.

Comment: But there is the notifyDataSetChanged method in the BaseAdapter class. The adapter I've added to the ListView is a SimpleCursorAdapter which is a subclass of BaseAdapter - so I should be able to somehow get the SimpleCursorAdapter in the ListView onItemClick method, right?

Comment: If its a instance of SimpleCursorAdapter then typecast it to base adapter and call notifyDataSetInvalidated().

Comment: The problem is that the onItemClick event passes in an AdapterView (parent), and performing getAdapter() returns a HeaderViewListAdapter.
When I use getWrappedAdapter() this returns a ListAdapter and unfortunately BaseAdapter is a subclass of this, so I can't yet use the notify methods even though in this instance the underlying adapter of the ListView is a SimpleCursorAdapter. How can I get a reference back to the ListView's implemented adapter?

Comment: You're right, I needed to typecast the ListAdapter:

HeaderViewListAdapter adapterwrap = (HeaderViewListAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) adapterwrap.getWrappedAdapter();

Answer (score 5):

You can also get to the BaseAdapter via your custom adapter as show in the following code fragment:

```
public class HeaderViewListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

...

  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> This throws an error because the object returned is of class
>   HeaderViewListAdapter, which for reasons unknown isn't a subclass of
>   BaseAdapter.

```
((BaseAdapter) ((HeaderViewListAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call any method to refresh your adapter client when you work with cursor.
Instead, after any operation you have to "Notify the changes" using `getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`

For example:

```
context.getContentResolver().update(SomeURI.CONTENT_URI, values, null,null);
context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(SomeURI.CONTENT_URI, null);
```

Your `viewclient (Listview, Gridview, Whatever)` will change automatically even you're using a  custom adapter or not.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I found much easier way ..just call `this.onCreate(null)` that will reload complete create method but the activity remains same .