# activity crashes when going back home

Tags: java, android, database

I have an edit task activity with a single edittext view. When i click the back button on the action bar, the database is updated and the log even registers it, but the activity crashes while going back. The main activity does display the text that was added in the task activity. 
Here is the code for the home button:

```
public class NewTask extends Activity {
protected TaskerDbHelper db;
MyAdapter adapt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_task);
    db = new TaskerDbHelper(this);
    setupActionBar();
}

private void setupActionBar() {

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_task, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String s = t.getText().toString();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "enter the task description first!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            Task task = new Task(s, 0);
            db.addTask(task);
            Log.d("tasker", "data added");
            //t.setText("");
            //adapt.add(task);
            adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Whats wrong?

Here is the log:

```
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at com.example.tasker.NewTask.onOptionsItemSelected(NewTask.java:62)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2552)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:167)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
08-16 17:56:05.117: E/AndroidRuntime(6162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what do you have line 62 in NewTask.java?

Comment: this : adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: how do you initialize adapt?

Comment: looks like it doenst know the refernce for the adapter anymore.

Comment: how did you initialize the adapter, e.g         arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songsArray);

Comment: just updated the code, now check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking if the adapter is null first

```
if(adapt != null) {
    adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
   // Initialize and do other stuff with it
}
```

And in the declaration, declare adapt like this

```
public MyAdapter adapt;
```

I can see that your using a custom adapter class. I think the problem may also be there in the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. Can you post it?

Comment: The adapter is null, i added a log.v statement to check it. 
I am using the stcok notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: You never actually initalize it. Try putting something like this in onCreate(): adapt = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

Answer (score 0):

```
if(adapt != null) {
    adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
    adapt = new Adapter();
    listview.setAdapter(adapt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the answer from Noah. he is overriding the notify() to access the BaseAdapter

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5327197/2074990